# Add two vertical UIStackView in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uistackview

I want to create a view like this:
[image]

A label followed by a table and another label followed by a bigger table.

What I have done so far: I created two vertical stack views and by adjusting directionalLayoutMargins.

Problem: I was able to get the view in the picture in zoom in display only and only the table on the top can scroll and display data.

The code for the view:

```
public override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let upperMainView = UIStackView()
   upperMainView.axis = .vertical
        
// Section label
   let upperSectionLabel = UILabel()
   upperMainView.addArrangedSubview(upperSectionLabel)
   upperMainView.setCustomSpacing(8, after: upperSectionLabel)
  // Table
   let upperTableView = UITableView()
   upperMainView.addArrangedSubview(upperTableView)
   upperMainView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
   upperMainView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 200, trailing: 8)
   self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   self.view.addConstraints(upperMainView.constraintsForFillingSuperview())

   let lowerMainView = UIStackView()
   lowerMainView.axis = .vertical
   // Section label
   let lowerSectionLabel = UILabel()
   lowerMainView.addArrangedSubview(lowerSectionLabel)
   lowerMainView.setCustomSpacing(8, after: lowerSectionLabel)
   // Table
   let lowerTableView = UITableView()
   lowerMainView.addArrangedSubview(lowerTableView)
   lowerMainView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
   lowerMainView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 408, trailing: 8)
   self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   self.view.addConstraints(upperMainView.constraintsForFillingSuperview())
}
```

I am wondering if this is the right approach for this view. How do you make the lower table scroll and display data?

Comment: Where is the code where you populate data?

Comment: 1) You don't add the stack views to the view hierarchy. 2) You don't set enough of the stack view properties (distribution, alignment, spacing). 3) You call `constraintsForFillingSuperview` on `upperMainView` twice and not at all for `lowerMainView`. I would think you want each one to take half of the screen. 4) You never set the data source of the table views so they won't get populated.